# Extract delta with Microsoft Team Foundation

Tags: java, ant, tfs

I am new to Microsoft Team foundation and I haven't found if there is any way to get  all the files that were modified in a branch. I fact, what I really would like is just get those files only in order to compile them and deploy this delta only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this via the TFS interface:

http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/2011/04/06/visualizing-changes-across-tfs-branches/

Or using PowerShell

http://blog.hackedbrain.com/2009/04/01/getting-a-distinct-list-of-changed-files-from-tfs-using-powershell/

Answer (score 1):

> get all the files that were modified in a branch

Not directly, but it can be built from the command line tool `tf`:

- `tf hist . -r` will list all the change sets containing an item in the current directory or a sub directory. Additional command line options support filtering by date.
- `tf changeset number` will list the content of the change set.

So get the list of changesets, get all the items, filter by folder and then reduce to unique items.

Comment: Note, I would probably use the PowerShell cmdlets from the TFS powertoys as shown in the second link on [Matthew Evans](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9735265/67392) answer. This avoids need to parse text output.